# why my ajax call is not getting generated as my js file which contain ajax is included inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

In below code , url is not called actually ajax is not working is there any jquery conflict or else ..

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://subscribe.php",
    data: params,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data == '') {
            alert(data);
            if (data.success == 1) {
                alert('Thank you for subscribing.');
                return false;
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

thanking you in advanced...

Comment: why you put ajax code in variable?? And when you want to call that??

Comment: What's the error are you facing?
Place error function and verify what's the error
`error:function(x,h,r){ ...}`

Comment: 1. you are talking about an iFrame and just show us the ajax call? 2. you are not telling us if and what javascript errors you get. 3. your url seems invalid, it doesn't even contain a domain name - so where should `https://subscribe.php` link to? 4. i hope you are aware about cross domain requests - and that they are blocked by browsers unless you are using the `dataType` "jsonp"

Comment: Add more details. Could be a lot of different things. try adding the contentType and the traditional.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is an asynchronous call and $.ajax() does not returns any response.

Please see the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ link to find out jQuery.ajax() usage.

Your code should be :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://subscribe.php",
  data : params,
  type : 'post',
  dataType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){ // this is a call back function.
            if (!data == ''){
                alert(data);
                if (data.success == 1){
                    alert('Thank you for subscribing.');
                    // Do your call
                }else{
                    alert(data.message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }              
});
```

You can use many other options in jQuery.ajax(). To know the detailed usage go to above mentioned URL.

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "subscribe.php",
  data : params,
  type : 'post',
  dataType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){ // this is a call back function.
                     alert(data);   
          
        }              
});this is also not working....

Comment: Add one error call back block in your ajax code and check for any error in console. For ajax usage detail see the link : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

`error: function(data){ console.log(data);}`

Comment: `$.ajax()` **does** return: `var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
 
xmlRequest.done( handleResponse );` (_that example even is on the exact same page you linked in your answer..._)